# Unable to define functions in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to simplify my code which passes a string to a function and pushes it to an array. Here is what I had before and it worked:

```js
var hi = [];
function hello(input) {
   console.log(input);
   hi.push(input);
}

var bye = [];
function goodbye(input) {
   console.log(input);
   bye.push(input);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello('example');">Should print example in console log</button>
<button onclick="goodbye('example2');">Should print example2 in console log</button>
```

I then changed this to have an array with each of the functions in it, like this:

```js
var options = [
  ["hello", "hi"],
  ["goodbye", "bye"]
];

options.forEach(function(option) {
  var arr1 = option[0]; // should be hello or goodbye
  var arr2 = option[1]; // should be hi or bye
  function arr1(input) {
    console.log(input);
    arr2.push(input);
  }
});
```

```html
<button onclick="hello('example');">
Should print example in console log
</button>

<button onclick="goodbye('example2');">
Should print example2 in console log
</button>
```

However, now when I click one of the buttons, it tells me that either the function `hello` or `goodbye` isn't defined.

*JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gaorxnto/*

Comment: Just call the function inside the loop, do not create the function in the loop.

Comment: First, you're creating a function called `arr1()` and not `hello()` or `goodbye()`.. You should do `Global[arr1] = function() {}` (and it'll aslo fix you [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/let) problem). But as @antfuentes87, it's not the good solution

Comment: where are the definition of hello and goodbye functions?

Comment: @antfuentes87 How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as I say on comment, doing `arr1 = function() {}` will not take the `arr1` value but will create a function called `arr1`.

You have to use the most global scope (window on client side)

```
let arr1 = 'hello'
window[arr1] = function() {}
```

Not tested solution:

```
var options = [
  ["hello", "hi"],
  ["goodbye", "bye"]
];
options.forEach(function(option) {
  window[option[1]] = [] // Init array
  window[option[0]] = function(val) { // Create event
    window[option[1]].push(val)
    console.log(val + " added to " + option[1])
  }
});
```

**-----UPDATE------**

Creating new global variable/scrope like that is not a really good solution.. Example what's append with?

```
var options = [
  ["var", "return"],
  ["function", "default"]
];
```

You'll try to create 2 arrays called `return` and `default` and 2 functions `var()` and `function()` who are all javascript reserved keywords.

`var()` or `return.push()` will create errors and you will be forced to use `window.var()` or `window.return.push()` (or `var option = 'var'; window[option]();`)

**Another solution**

```
// Store all your inputs on a single variable, ex:  results.hi = [1,2,3] 
let results={}; 

// A single function to call. ex: addTo(`hello`, 1)
function addTo(category, val) { 
  // Find the accosiate option
  let option = options.find(opt=> { return opt[0] === category })
  // First time, init the array
  if(!results[category]) { 
    results[category] = [] 
  } 
  // Push new value
  results[category].push(val)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arthur, I will try this. However I was interested in what antfuentes87 said about calling the function inside the loop. Is there a link to this anywhere?

Comment: No, i think it's another solution: create a single function, call it everytime by passing the category: `let results={}; function addTo(category, val) { let option = options.find(opt=> { return opt[0] === category}); if(!results[category]) { results[category] = [] } results[category].push(val);  }` (no tested)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll stick to your first solution because I understand it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you create the function in the loop so you cant reach it. attach it to the window so the dom can access it

```js
var options = [
  ["hello", "hi"],
  ["goodbye", "bye"]
];

options.forEach(function(option) {
  var arr1 = option[0]; // should be hello or goodbye
  var arr2 = option[1]; // should be hi or bye
  window[arr1] = function(input) {
    console.log(input);
  }
});
```

```
https://jsfiddle.net/gaorxnto/2/
```